# Align 2 <p> elements on same line

Tags: html

Align 2 `<p>` elements on same line

I wanna align both `<p>` elements on same line but one to left other to the right.

```html
<p style="text-align:left">Copyright &copy; {$date_year} {$companyname}. All Rights Reserved.</p><p style="text-align:right"><a href="url">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="url">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="url">Contact Us</a></p>
```

When i try to do this the 2nd one drops to a new line so it appears right side but under the line i want it to be on.

Comment: Easiest way: replace the paragraph tags with span tags. (and wrap them both in a paragraph tags). Alternative approach in the CSS declare a width for the paragraph tags and set their display to inline

Answer (score 0):

Replace `style="text-align:left"` to `style="float: left"`
Use below code

```
<p style="float: left">Copyright &copy; {$date_year}
    {$companyname}. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p style="float: right">
    <a href="url">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="url">Privacy Policy</a> |
    <a href="url">Contact Us</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you i missed out `float` i appreciate the assistance and this is solved sincere thanks.

Comment: Click on Tick mark for my Answer(Accept it), if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use float property for same line...adjust widht as you want.

```
<p style="float: left; width: 50%;">Copyright &copy; {$date_year} {$companyname}. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p style="float: left; width: 50%;"><a href="url">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="url">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="url">Contact Us</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.right {
    float:right;
    width: 50%
}
.left{
    float:left;
    width: 50%
}
```

```html
<p class="left">Copyright &copy; {$date_year} {$companyname}. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p class="right">
   <a href="url">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="url">Privacy Policy</a> |
    <a href="url">Contact Us</a>
</p>
```